# SQL Query - Two Columns, Duplicate Data - Need Most frequent

Tags: sql

I could use a little guidance on a query that I am trying to create in Access. Here is what my data looks like:

```
UserName    ComputerName

John    Computer 1
John    Computer 1
John    Computer 1
John    Computer 1
John    Computer 2
John    Computer 2
Sally   Computer 1
Sally   Computer 1
Sally   Computer 2
Mike    Computer 1
Megan   Computer 2
```

I would like retrieve the ComputerName that is accessed the most by each user. Here is what I would like to see.

```
John         Computer 1
Sally        Computer 1
Mike         Computer 1
Megan        Computer 2
```

As you can see there are duplicate entries in the UserName field (John, Sally) but it is possible that there is only a single instance of a name (Mike, Megan) also in that field.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Darin

Comment: Is there an `id` or something to identify the most *frequent*?

Comment: John and Sally both have access to "Computer 1" and "Computer 2". Do you only want to get the first accessible computer, or would like to edit your question?

Comment: There is no ID. To be more clear, these are Citrix log files that shows which users are connecting to Citrix and which machine they are using to connect. Many users are roaming and connect from several different machines. I am trying to determine the machine that each unique user is using the most.

Comment: Any additional suggestions from anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below uses a self join to get the most popular computer name for each user.

```
select t1.UserName, t1.ComputerName from (
    select UserName, ComputerName, count(*) as cnt
    from mytable
    group by UserName, ComputerName
) as t1 left join (
    select UserName, ComputerName, count(*) as cnt
    from mytable
    group by UserName, ComputerName
) as t2 on t1.UserName = t2.UserName and t2.cnt > t1.cnt
group by t1.UserName, t1.ComputerName
having count(t2.cnt) = 0
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. I tried this too and I'm getting a Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'count(*) cnt' error. Does this have anything to do with the fact that I am using MS Access?

Comment: CORRECTION. This did not work as it is returning some duplicate UserNames. I need the username with the computer name that the accessed the most.

Comment: @Darin if you're getting duplicates then there are probably ties for the most frequently accessed company per user

Comment: FuzzyTree. Thank you. You are absolutely correct. I've been working with this so much over the past day or so that I am beginning to lose my mind.